# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError android/support/v7/AppCompat/

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

After starting my eclipse today, any project I run returns the following error:

```
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406): Process: be.thomasmore.powerfactory, PID: 5406
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field abc_screen_toolbar of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$layout; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout' appears in /data/app/be.thomasmore.powerfactory-2/base.apk)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:299)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at be.thomasmore.powerfactory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
08-06 08:01:23.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Last night everything was still working fine..

Any ideas?

Comment: you didn't setup(add) appcompat library properly ... (did you add only a jar?) ... similar questions were asked many times, did you follow any of em?

Comment: Moved to Android studio , and import appcompat from gradle

Comment: or please read http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-setting-up-actionbarcompat-support-library-in-eclipse/

Comment: http://blog.axxg.de/android-support-library-v7-appcompat-eclipse-einbinden/

Comment: I've taken a look at the other solutions and the only one I haven't tried yet is rolling back the support library to v20. 

@IntelliJAmiya I've read both and I imported appcompat v7 as shown in the first link and I can't change the project build target of my appcompat as described in the second link. I can only select Android 4.4W.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently I needed to update my SDK tools and SDK platform-tools, after that I was able to select 5.1.1 as build target for my appcompat v7 library project.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Android Studio 2.0 and Android Support Library 23.3.0. The error was

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field AppCompatTheme of type
```

I solved it by going to Android SDK Manager.
Updates were available for following:

- Android SDK Build Tools
- Android SDK Tools
- Android Support Library
- Google Repository

Updated and ran the app again, that solved the problem.

**Edit:**

If you have already updated above mentioned things and still have problems,
as @mparkes pointed out in comment, check if you have updated the `build.gradle(app)` file to use the latest library as following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Then rebuild the project: `Build Menu > Rebuild Project`

Comment: I also had the same problem and everything had already been updated.  I had just changed my grade file to compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' I solved it with build -> rebuild

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem after upgrading to Android Studio 2.0. In my case it was Instant Run issue. There is a [bug in AOSP Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201855).

So disabling Instant Run helped me.

- Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
- Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.

Comment: it also works if you clean and rebuild the project. also, this happens on recent AS build as well (2.1.2 for example)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I´ve used v7:23.3.0 in my Library Project, but v7:23.0.0 in the actual app. This means, the library was compiled against a higher version than it got in the app.