# Actionbar menu crashing on long-press

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

**I have a menu item in the actionbar like below.**

[image]

**Menu code:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.vroom, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_sos) {
        sos_dialog();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Menu XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sos"
        android:title="SOS"
        android:icon="@drawable/fab_sos"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**Single click works as usual but if long-pressed it crashes with the following error:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field message of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id' appears in /data/app/bd.com.vroom-1/base.apk:classes6.dex)
                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.TooltipPopup.<init>(TooltipPopup.java:60)
                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.show(TooltipCompatHandler.java:154)
                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.onLongClick(TooltipCompatHandler.java:103)
                                                              at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:5714)
                                                              at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5672)
                                                              at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9415)
                                                              at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5690)
                                                              at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:22398)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**Though long-press works fine if icon is removed from menu xml. Any kind of suggestions to solve the crash will be highly appreciated.**

**build.gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bd.com.vroom"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    ext {
        support_library_version = "26.1.0"
        google_play_services_version = "11.0.1"
    }

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:${support_library_version}"

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${google_play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${google_play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${google_play_services_version}"

    compile('com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.17-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.4'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:1.0.0-beta5'
    compile 'noman.placesapi:placesAPI:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: @WaqarKhan: Tried it before, don't work.

Comment: can you post your activity..

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle. you may be using deprecated libs around your code

Comment: Update sdk tools and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855409/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: @WaqarKhan buld.gradle posted.

Comment: @Anonymous Tried that also, didn't work. Here is the build.gradle after updating: https://pastebin.com/0FixGAuh

Comment: Try to remove     compile "com.android.support:support-v13:${support_library_version}" and check again

Comment: @Anonymous: Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Found this on the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64594124

Basically if you have your own tooltip.xml file it will conflict with the new tooltip of the design library.

I had a NoSuchFieldError after updating to Android Support Library 26.1.0 with the stacktrace posted below. But renaming my own tooltip.xml solved the issue as well.

Comment: I don't have any `tooltip.xml`.